# Docker Compose + Postgres: Expose port

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am currently trying to use Docker for my new Django/Postgres project. I am working on a Mac and usually use Postico to quickly connect to my database.

I used to connect like here:

[image]

I used the official Docker documentation to setup docker-compose. I now have the issue, that I can't connect via Postico to the postgres db. It seems to me that the problem comes from the ports not being exposed.

[image]

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just map the port to the host machine, add this to the `db` service in your Compose file:

```
ports:
  - "5432:5432"
```

Also make sure to set the postgres password variable in the compose file like this

```
environment:
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
```

The default user is postgres, you can change it with the `POSTGRES_USER` variable.

You can read about the usage of the image with all options here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

Comment: This is not working. I still can not access via localhost:5432

Comment: In the newer compose versions, you can't put it as string. You have to put `- 5432:5432` not `- "5432:5432". I believe this is a bug, and will be fixed eventually, but you can get a random port if you use string.

Answer (score 3):

By default Compose sets up a single network for your app.

Each container can be accessed by the name of the service in the compose file.

In your case you don't have to expose the port to the host machine for your web app to have access to it. You can simply use `db` as the hostname for postgres (and `5432` for the port) from any other service running on the same compose.

Actually a very similar example is provided in the docker compose documentation:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/